# Intercept response ( including validation responses ) before sending it to end user

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I have a CORS middleware in my application that i have registered as global middleware. SO, as supposed, it should run in every http request. My end goal is to store every request and their responses including validator error responses in my DB.Everything is working fine but when any of my request fails because of validator rules it does not passes through my CORS middleware terminate method. Please any help.

I have registered my CORS middleware as global middleware to run for every HTTP request and it almost full fill my requirments of logging every request and response but it is not logging validator failure responses.

//  bootstrap/app.php

```
$app->middleware([
App\Http\Middleware\ExampleMiddleware::class,
App\Http\Middleware\CORS::class
]);

// App/Http/Middleware/CORS

// Log every request in the DB after response is ready to be dispatched
public function terminate($request, $response){
/// Code to intercept and store values in DB
}
```

I need help in whether i am doing something wrong or i should go for different direction. I just want to log every request and response including validator failure responses in my DB using

Answer (score 0):

For logging requests you can do something like

```
<?php

namespace App\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class LogRequests
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $this->logRequest($request);

        $response = $next($request);

        return $response;
    }

    private function logRequest($request)
    {
        $validation = Validator::make($request->toArray(),[
           'etc' => 'required',
        ]);

        if ($validation->fails()) {
          $firstError = $validation->errors()->first();
          $orJson = $validation->errors()->toJson()
          // DB::insert should go here
        }

    }
}
```

You will have to register it as well, goto `app/Http/Kernel.php` and put it under global middleware or any group.

Comment: thanks for the idea. But not all my requests have validator rules assigned to them and as you mentioned using Validator and request object every time to check whether it fails or not and if fails save to DB. So, if i go for this one, my routes with validator rules will work fine but what will be the case for the routes that does not have any rules assigned for them

Comment: Instead of doing it in middleware, i made a function inside my model and for validator errors i used my model function in App\Exception\Handler.php to get exceptions errors and all the request values. I just don't know whether it's okk this way or not

Comment: I am not sure about your use case, in case of monitoring requests i would rather use a middleware. If you want to monitor certain routes you can always use route() global function to check for your routes and escape if something is not true.

Comment: I dont think saving exceptions into db is a good idea, its not structured data you are better off with files. But again i am not sure about your use case.